# createERFilterNM1 - optimal settings

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm using the Scene Text Detection features of OpenCV and have some troubles finding the optimal parameters for createERFilterNM1. Here is what the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/erfilter.html#createerfilternm1) states:

> C++: Ptr createERFilterNM1(const Ptr&
>   cb, int thresholdDelta=1, float minArea=0.00025, float maxArea=0.13,
>   float minProbability=0.4, bool nonMaxSuppression=true, float
>   minProbabilityDiff=0.1 ) Parameters:
>
> - cb – Callback with the classifier. Default classifier can be implicitly load with function loadClassifierNM1(), e.g. from file in
>     samples/cpp/trained_classifierNM1.xml
> - thresholdDelta – Threshold step in subsequent thresholds when extracting the component tree
> - minArea – The minimum area (% of image size) allowed for retreived ER’s
> - maxArea – The maximum area (% of image size) allowed for retreived ER’s
> - minProbability – The minimum probability P(er|character) allowed for retreived ER’s
> - nonMaxSuppression – Whenever non-maximum suppression is done over the branch probabilities
> - minProbabilityDiff – The minimum probability difference between local maxima and local minima ERs

The default values are not the same as in the [example](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.cpp). So I wonder what the optimal settings are.

Would it be possible to optimize the settings when I know the fontsize of the to-detect-text? Maybe by setting the max/minArea to the size of a letter? I also don't understand what the minProbabilityDiff means.